# How to create a calendar table (date dimension) in pandas

Tags: pandas

A table of dates with primary keys is sometimes used in databse design.

```
| date_id |     Date       |    Record_timestamp |  Day      |  Week |  Month |     Quarter |   Year_half |     Year |
|---------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+----------|
|       0 |     2000-01-01 |    NaN              |  Saturday |  52   |  1     |     1       |   1         |     2000 |
|       1 |     2000-01-02 |    NaN              |  Sunday   |  52   |  1     |     1       |   1         |     2000 |
|       2 |     2000-01-03 |    NaN              |  Monday   |  1    |  1     |     1       |   1         |     2000 |
```

How to do it in pandas?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, seems to be a self answer, therefore does show some research... Perhaps one annoying part is the pipes, best to just paste the DataFrame output from the terminal, that way it can be read in using read_clipboard.

Comment: Yup, I've saved it here for later and tested out the self answer of SO. I'll remember the pipes next time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a little cleaner with the [`dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor):

```
In [11]: def create_date_table2(start='2000-01-01', end='2050-12-31'):
    ...:     df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
    ...:     df["Day"] = df.Date.dt.weekday_name
    ...:     df["Week"] = df.Date.dt.weekofyear
    ...:     df["Quarter"] = df.Date.dt.quarter
    ...:     df["Year"] = df.Date.dt.year
    ...:     df["Year_half"] = (df.Quarter + 1) // 2
    ...:     return df

In [12]: create_date_table2().head()
Out[12]:
        Date        Day  Week  Quarter  Year  Year_half
0 2000-01-01   Saturday    52        1  2000          1
1 2000-01-02     Sunday    52        1  2000          1
2 2000-01-03     Monday     1        1  2000          1
3 2000-01-04    Tuesday     1        1  2000          1
4 2000-01-05  Wednesday     1        1  2000          1

In [13]: create_date_table2().tail()
Out[13]:
            Date        Day  Week  Quarter  Year  Year_half
18623 2050-12-27    Tuesday    52        4  2050          2
18624 2050-12-28  Wednesday    52        4  2050          2
18625 2050-12-29   Thursday    52        4  2050          2
18626 2050-12-30     Friday    52        4  2050          2
18627 2050-12-31   Saturday    52        4  2050          2
```

*Note: you may like to calculate these on the fly rather than store them as columns!*

Comment: Sweet, thank you! I am preparing a table for import to a database, that's why I create it in advance.

Comment: Interestingly it seems [`dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) doesn't exist, might be a bug. But if you need to epoch you can use `.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9`.

Comment: How can we add hour to it ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this function

```
def create_date_table(start='2000-01-01', end='2050-12-31'):
    start_ts = pd.to_datetime(start).date()

    end_ts = pd.to_datetime(end).date()

    # record timetsamp is empty for now
    dates =  pd.DataFrame(columns=['Record_timestamp'],
        index=pd.date_range(start_ts, end_ts))
    dates.index.name = 'Date'

    days_names = {
        i: name
        for i, name
        in enumerate(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
                      'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 
                      'Sunday'])
    }

    dates['Day'] = dates.index.dayofweek.map(days_names.get)
    dates['Week'] = dates.index.week
    dates['Month'] = dates.index.month
    dates['Quarter'] = dates.index.quarter
    dates['Year_half'] = dates.index.month.map(lambda mth: 1 if mth <7 else 2)
    dates['Year'] = dates.index.year
    dates.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dates.index.name = 'date_id'
    return dates
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked Andy and Robin's approaches and modified their `create_date_table`s slightly for my needs in case you are interested in having a determinisitic `date_id`. I find this helpful so that in other future ETL processes, given a date, won't need to worry about extra look-up steps.

```
def create_date_table3(start='1990-01-01', end='2080-12-31'):
   df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
   df["week_day"] = df.date.dt.weekday_name
   df["day"] = df.date.dt.day
   df["month"] = df.date.dt.month
   df["week"] = df.date.dt.weekofyear
   df["quarter"] = df.date.dt.quarter
   df["year"] = df.date.dt.year
   df.insert(0, 'date_id', (df.year.astype(str) + df.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df.day.astype(str).str.zfill(2)).astype(int))
   return df
```