# Creating year week based on date with different start date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df`

```
date

2021-03-12
2021-03-17
...
2022-05-21
2022-08-17
```

I am trying to add a column `year_week`, but my year week starts at `2021-06-28`, which is the first day of July.

I tried:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year_week'] = (df['date'] - timedelta(days=datetime(2021, 6, 24).timetuple()
                               .tm_yday)).dt.isocalendar().week
```

I played around with the `timedelta` `days` values so that the `2021-06-28` has a value of `1`.

But then I got problems with previous & dates exceeding my start date + 1 year:

```
2021-03-12 has a value of 38
2022-08-17 has a value of 8
```

So it looks like the valid period is from `2021-06-28` + `1 year`.

```
date            year_week

2021-03-12      38  # LY38
2021-03-17      39  # LY39
2021-06-28      1   # correct
...
2022-05-21      47  # correct
2022-08-17      8   # NY8
```

Is there a way to get around this? As I am aggregating the data by year week I get incorrect results due to the past & upcoming dates. I would want to have negative dates for the days before `2021-06-28` or `LY38` denoting that its the year week of the last year, accordingly year weeks of 52+ or `NY8` denoting that this is the `8th` week of the next year?

Comment: do you not have a business calendar to join on?

Comment: I do not have any other data than this.

Comment: what do you want as result if you have a date that is more than a year away? let's say for `2023-08-17`

Comment: @Ben.T, For everything less or more than a year away I would like to have `+1LY8 / +2LY8` and `+1NY8 / +2NY8`

Comment: I think this is a loose duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150709/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-date-dimension-in-pandas - there are lots of resources for creating business calendars, mostly in SQL but you can transpose the logic to Python pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, I added two dates more than a year away. You need the `isocalendar` from the difference between the date column and the `dayofyear` of your specific date. Then you can select the different scenario depending on the `year` of your specific date. use `np.select` for the different result format.

```
#dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': ['2020-03-12',  '2021-03-12',  '2021-03-17', '2021-06-28',  
              '2022-05-21', '2022-08-17', '2023-08-17']
    }
)

# define start date
d = pd.to_datetime('2021-6-24')

# remove the nomber of day of year from each date
s = (pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - pd.Timedelta(days=d.day_of_year)
    ).dt.isocalendar()

# get the difference in year
m = (s['year'].astype('int32') - d.year)

# all condition of result depending on year difference
conds = [m.eq(0), m.eq(-1), m.eq(1), m.lt(-1), m.gt(1)]
choices =  ['', 'LY','NY',(m+1).astype(str)+'LY', '+'+(m-1).astype(str)+'NY']

# create the column
df['res'] = np.select(conds, choices) + s['week'].astype(str)

print(df)
         date     res
0  2020-03-12  -1LY38
1  2021-03-12    LY38
2  2021-03-17    LY39
3  2021-06-28       1
4  2022-05-21      47
5  2022-08-17     NY8
6  2023-08-17   +1NY8
```

Comment: This throws `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'day_of_year'`.

Comment: I managed to fix that error, but now `np.select(conds, choices)` throws `TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis how did you fix the error on the Timestamp.day_of_year?

Comment: I used `pd.Timedelta(days=d.timetuple().tm_yday)).dt.isocalendar()` but tjat error with `boolean ndarray` still remains.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis hmm by using `pd.Timedelta(days=d.timetuple().tm_yday)`  instead of `pd.Timedelta(days=d.day_of_year)` works on my side, at least with the data sample. please elaborate on where the error can come from, otherwise I can't help further

Answer (score -1):

I think
pandas period_range can be of some help

```
pd.Series(pd.period_range("6/28/2017", freq="W", periods=Number of weeks you want))
```