# Invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray using np.select

Tags: python, numpy, date

I have a piece of code which meant to create year_week out of datetimes. My startdate is different from the normal year start and I am trying to add `LY`, `NY`, `+LY` prefixes if the year is below or above my year, which starts at `2021-06-24` and ends in `2022-06-04` denoting `LY = last year` and `NY = next year`.

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68590716/creating-year-week-based-on-date-with-different-start-date/68591910#68591910).

```
a['date'].sample(5)

13775   2021-09-06
7174    2021-08-03
17227   2021-09-06
24346   2021-07-19
23459   2021-08-02


a['date'].isna().value_counts()
False    3970

len(a)
3970
```

```
a['date'].fillna('2000-01-01', inplace=True)
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['revdat'])

# define start date
d = pd.to_datetime('2021-6-24')

# remove the number of day of year from each date
s = (pd.to_datetime(a['date']) - pd.Timedelta(days=d.timetuple().tm_yday)
    ).dt.isocalendar()

# get the difference in year
m = (s['year'].astype('Int64') - d.year)

# all condition of result depending on year difference
conds = [m.eq(0), m.eq(-1), m.eq(1), m.lt(-1), m.gt(1)]
choices =  ['', 'LY','NY',(m+1).astype(str)+'LY', '+'+(m-1).astype(str)+'NY']

# create the column
a['year_week'] = np.select(conds, choices) + s['week'].astype(str)
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

I thought it was because previously `a['revdat']` had 2 `na` values which I now filled using `a['revdat'].fillna('2000-01-01', inplace=True)` but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: what is `m.eq(0)`?

Comment: The difference in years from the date I am checking. So that if the date falls in my range of `2021-06-24` and `2022-06-04` it simply has the `week_number` rather than a suffix of `NY` or `LY`.

Comment: I didn't want a word description.  You need to examine the actual value, and see if it conforms to `select's` specification.  According to the error it is the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.select()` expects an ndarray of type `bool`. When using `.eq()` you will return a Series that is type `boolean` instead of `bool`. All you have to do to fix the issue is to cast it to the correct type with `.astype(bool)`.

Note that even if you are using eq as part of a larger logical expression, the result will have the `boolean` type.

Comment: In my case dtype was numpy.bool_  Your fix eliminated the TypeError but interestingly the dtype after adding astype(bool was still numpy.bool_